# Can Autohotkey detect when a KVM switch is activated?

Tags: autohotkey, kvm

Can Autohotkey detect when a KVM switch is activated? Currently I have:

```
OnMessage(0x219, "notify_change")
```

It notifies me when the KVM switch button is pressed, but also when anything else is plugged in or unplugged, plus other times I don't know why. Is there any way to detect just that the switch button was pressed and/or the keyboard, monitor, and mouse switched from one computer to another?

Comment: You'd have to get a list of connected devices and see which ones are there (or not there). This might give you a start. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=69380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to kindall pointing me in the right direction, I have an answer:

First, get all the functions from here and save them in devicelist.ahk https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=69380

Then use this code to see if the keyboard is plugged in. If it is not plugged in, that would mean the KVM switch is not turned to this computer.

```
#include %a_scriptdir%\devicelist.ahk

notify_change(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd) 
{ 
    keyboard := 0
    oArray := JEE_DeviceList("`r`n")
    for _, oObj in oArray {
        for vKey, vValue in oObj {
            if (instr(vValue, "Keyboard")) {
                keyboard := 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```